# Right-clicking on any program in Kubuntu 23.04 does not give the option to "start with discrete video card"

Tags: kubuntu, kde, nvidia-optimus, 23.04

I'm using an Nvidia video card. In Gnome, right-clicking on any program gives me the option to "Start with a discrete video card", but in KDE Plasma this option is missing.How do I add this option to the right click menu?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I was so distracted that I confused kubuntu with kde neon, I entered the title wrong, sorry. I have this problem with Kubuntu 23.04.